# When was there a dog in ISS's Kibo module?

Tags: identify-this-object, animals, reduced-gravity-sports

The interesting question [What living organisms adapt to 0 gravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26952/12102) includes several GIF images. One if them is shown below, that of (apparently) a dog in a NASA suit floating around in the ISS's [Japanese Experiment Module (JEM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibo_(ISS_module)), nicknamed Kibo.

It is reminiscent of [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV81O.gif) shown in [Can you swim in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8073/12102)

Whaaaaa??? ;-)

[image]

Comment: Unconfirmed, but comments suggest the dog was filmed separately and inserted into Kibo image for a Japanese Bank commercial. http://www.everydaysciencestuff.com/space-dog/.

Comment: on NASA’s Reduced Gravity Aircraft, aka. The Vomit Comet.

Comment: @Muze if that's the answer, and it can be confirmed, then feel free to post an answer!

Comment: @uhoh ok working on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No dog was ever on the ISS. 
This is from an advert of a Japanese cell phone provider called SoftBank. Here's the full video:

The ad is part of a series. This episode is called "父と交信" or (Communicating with Dad; 父/dad being the dogs name). I found no hint that the production was in any way extraordinary.

It appears to be filmed on a green screen background. My guess is that the body is a puppet and the head was later composed in. For the paddling shot, it may be that the space suit hides a harness that the dog was kept in. From walking a dog in a harness once I remember that if you lift it up by the harness and keep it close to the ground it may do the dog paddling shown.

Comment: Now I'm going to spend the rest of the day watching Japanese TV commercials. Favorite so far: https://youtu.be/lDUOmY80GhU

Comment: "No dog was ever on the ISS"  The crew of STS-88 would disagree!  Woof!  https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/e4AAAOSwNSxVQrGk/s-l300.jpg

Comment: Wait, is this the same SoftBank as had some (public? leaked?) PowerPoint on business strategy that looks like something out of Neon Genesis Evangelion?

Comment: @ikrase The very same. They are terrible. Regular cell phone contracts in Japan are extremely overpriced, and all that money gets sunken into completely batshit insane silicon valley business ventures.