# Who are these people inside Apollo Command Module (presumably posing for advertisement photoshoot)?

Tags: apollo-program, history

In an attempt to find photos from any of Apollo missions that portray Sony TC-50 voice recorder/player that was used in these missions I came across the following picture:
[image]

There is better quality of the picture on [this webpage](http://www.thevintageknob.org/sony-TC-50.html) (the page doesn't allow copying or even providing direct link to the photo).

The photo, apparently, is part of a Sony advertisement.

Mentioned above webpage claims that we see Eugene Cernan and John Young:

> Holding the TC-50 is Eugene A. Cernan, Lunar Module Pilot ; behind him is John W. Young, Command Module Pilot.

I've looked through quite a few photos of Cernan and Young available on internet, and these two people on the photo above don't really resemble them to me (but I might be mistaking, of course).

There are few reasons why I assumed this was a dedicated photoshoot (rather than a photo from a mission or training):

- suits and gloves look different (there is USA flag but no NASA logo)
- lighting looks perfectly arranged for a photoshoot
- both men don't seem to be in a natural pose for a candid shot.

I've also found [another Sony advertisement](https://www.nypl.org/blog/2019/07/16/moon-madness-ad-research-e-resources) published in Life Magazine, August 8, 1969.
Below is the cropped part of it:
[image]
This seems to be a photo from another angle of the same scene as the first shot.

Am I mistaking, and these were real NASA astronauts on a mission/training (in this case I would appreciate if someone could recognize who these astronauts were), or were they just a photo models for dedicated photoshoot?

Comment: apparently [this ISS astronaut](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26969/12102) was actually photoshopped in Japan as well, and [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8073/12102) was possibly hand-drawn there. Perhaps the models in the capsule were borrowed from a [Kraftwerk album cover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9SvN.jpg)?

Answer (score 5):

I found some right-facing contemporary shots of the two men (photo credits: NASA) and laid them beside the men in the ad.

Top right picture is Cernan, bottom right picture is Young.

[image]

My conclusion: nope.